# Android: Detect if View can be drawn

Tags: android

I have a View that depending on the available screen space does not need to be visible. Is there an easy way to detect if it will fit on the screen properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Job for having different layouts depending on screen size.  If you set up your layout folders by screen size, you can specify different layouts for a small or a large screen:

```
layout-small
  -> my_layout.xml
layout-large
  -> my_layout.xml
layout-600sw # tablet
  -> my_layout.xml
```

etc.

See [this blog post](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for reference